# Embedding User Name in Default Save Name

Tags: microsoft-word

The Title property for MS Word document is also used for the default name when a user saves a document. This is particularly helpful for .dotx files where the default save name would be Document.docx or something else if no title were present.

Is there any variable that could be put in the property or some other method that would allow the user's user name to be included in the default save name?

For instance: For a Title property of "'Feedback Form" I would like the default save name to be "'Feedback Form Sally Smith.docx'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be done with a Global add-in that trapped the Save As Event. Another type of add-in that could perform this is a VSTO COM Add-in and it would trap the Before Save events. Finally, a macro driven template attached to the document could also perform this function.

Other than a programmatic solution, there is not a standard property setting that can perform a function like you are requesting.